# Why can't func_num_args be an argument?

Tags: php

Consider the following example:

```
// does not work
foo( func_num_args() );

// works
$args = func_num_args();
foo( $args );
```

Why specifically does the former fail and the latter work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note:**
>
> Because this function depends on the current scope to determine
> parameter details, it cannot be used as a function parameter in
> versions prior to 5.3.0. If this value must be passed, the results
> should be assigned to a variable, and that variable should be passed.
>
> http://php.net/func_num_args

In other words: because of the way this function works internally. The runtime is in a different state when it's inside a regular function body and when it's evaluating expressions to be used as parameters to another function. This was changed in 5.3.

Comment: +1 Nice catch. I was about about to post a comment saying "works for me". (But I'm using the newest version of php...)

Comment: I understand that, what I don't understand is how assigning the value to a variable and passing the variable is different from just passing the function.

Comment: @Moses Just added my interpretation of it. Realize that this function is pretty much an internal hack of the runtime. Until 5.3 it wasn't even a very good hack.